# Django Rest - Adding query parameter data in viewset

Tags: django, rest, frameworks, django-rest-framework

In the documentation for dynamic extension of DRF they describe the possibility to to add query parameters through the viewset.([instructions](https://github.com/AltSchool/dynamic-rest/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst#query-parameter-injection))
These added query parameters act as if they were being passed in the url request, thereby triggering dynamic actions available through the extension.
But I can't get this to work. It seems impossible to make the serializer or router to recognize the alteration of the request instance.
Any suggestions as to where to learn more about how this works, or alternative ways to do it would be greatly appreciated.

```
class EventViewSet(DynamicModelViewSet):
    # …

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # sideload location by default
        request.query_params.add('include[]', 'location.')

        # filter for status=current by default
        status = request.query_params.get('filter{status}')
        if not status:
            request.query_params.add('filter{status}','current')

        return super(EventViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you share more specifically what params you are trying to add, or how the serializer/router needs to recognise them?

Comment: Actually I have managed to make it work when I try to redefine 'list' method. Then I can adde query params like the ones in the example above. dynamic-rest recognizes them, and the serializer output is altered. It is when i try to redefine 'retrieve' method that the query params seem to be ignored

Comment: Actually I have managed to redefine the 'list' method with success. Here dynamic-rest recognizes the query params, like in the example and alters the serialized output. But when I try the same with redefining 'retrieve' method, the query params seem to be ignored.